# C# Validate Signature

Tags: c#, .net, security, http, certificate

I have the following code to sign my data before sending it (http):

```
    internal static byte[] Encode(byte[] arMessage, string signerCert, string signerPassword)
            {
                X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(signerCert, signerPassword);
                //debug data
                var msg = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(arMessage);
                //--
                ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(arMessage);

                SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true); // <- true detaches the signature
                CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(cert);

                signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);
                byte[] signature = signedCms.Encode();

                return signature;
            }
```

I can see the signature after doing the following:

```
    string sig = Convert.ToBase64String(bSignature) + MESSAGE_SEPARATOR;
    //this will be included in the message:
    bSignature = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sig);

    //debug data, see the signature:
    string deb8 = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bSignature);
    //--
```

For example:

```
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
```

This is what I have in the received message.
So **the question** is: how to validate the signature of the received message on the recipient (has the .cer file provided)?
Thanks in advance

Edit 1:

I tried to follow the Daniel Hilgarth's logic but it didn't worked.
A few times I met the "ASN Bad tag value" exception.
To make it easier, I hardcoded the message being used to generate the signature
So, on the receiver I have 2 things: the original message and the signature generated for it:

```
    //Signature from the message  (string in ASCII)
    var signatureKey = GetSignatureFromSignatureMessage(signatureMessage, boundary);
    //Original sent message (the arMessage itself used in Encode method above, converted to string from byte) 
    var messageOriginal =
        "Content-Type: application/EDIFACT\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\nSome short text.\r\nVery short.";
```

I need to check if the signature corresponds this message.
So I am trying to do something like this:

```
//contentInfo from the original message.
ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageOriginal));

//SingedCms from the contentInfo above
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);

//Here, I believe, I am attaching the signature I have to the Cms    
 signedCms.Decode(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureKey));

//checking?
signedCms.CheckSignature(true);
```

And I get exceptions on decode part.

Any advices?

Edit 2: 
**Solution:**
The direction given by Daniel Hilgarth is right.
My problem was that the sender encoded the key few times:
Base64 byte array -> Base64String -> ASCII byte array -> ASCII string -> Send_message
The receiver was receiving the data in ASCII already, doing:
ASCII String -> Byte array.
I had to convert everything back to base64 byte array to make it work.

```
    //Signature from the message (ASCII String)
    var signatureKey = GetSignatureFromSignatureMessage(signatureMessage, boundary);

    //Original Byte Array (Base64)
    var sigKeyBase = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureKey);

   //Original sent message
    var messageOriginal =
        "Content-Type: application/EDIFACT\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\nSome short text.\r\nVery short.";

    var messageOriginalByteASCII = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageOriginal);


    ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(messageOriginalByteASCII);
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
    signedCms.Decode(sigKeyBase);

    signedCms.CheckSignature(true);
```

In this case it passes Check.
P.S. Too bad ChekSignature doesn't return true or false. I'd be more comfortable imho. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm... maybe using [`SignedCms.CheckSignature`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.checksignature.aspx)?! Use it in conjunction with [`SignedCms.Decode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.decode.aspx). Basically, just use the reverse way you use to sign the document. An example with detached signature is available from the MSDN page:

```
// Create a ContentInfo object from the inner content obtained 
// independently from encodedMessage.
ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(innerContent);

// Create a new, detached SignedCms message.
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);

// encodedMessage is the encoded message received from 
// the sender.
signedCms.Decode(encodedMessage);

// Verify the signature without validating the 
// certificate.
signedCms.CheckSignature(true);
```

Comment: More details, please.
The signature is computed for the message arMessage. Later I send 1 packet containing both, the message and the signature (in ascii) to the recipient. He gets the packet (message + attached signature) and how is he supposed to validate it? SignedCms.CheckSignature doesn't have the signature itself as input?!

Comment: @Razp: Updated answer, please check

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.
I think I am doing something wrong, so I updated my original question.
Take a look at it, please.